# How to display a custom warning message on record save

Tags: lightning, configuration

I have a requirement wherein I have to display a warning message to the user on record save. It doesn't prevent records save, but just show's an error message.

I have been trying to think of the best solution but nothing makes sense. 
it doesn't make sense to display a component content based on record value's and that's something I was thinking of implementing.

What would be the best possible solution to show a 1 time warning message based on certain values whenever the user save's the record on record page.

Thanks

Comment: When you say warning, is it something the user has to acknowledge before the save can continue? Or is it just merely a `toast` that just shows when the save is occurring?

Comment: @BryanAnderson It's merely a toast which presents a message to the user and it does not prevent the record from getting saved.. The record would still be saved.. It's just that this message would be displayed only for a few conditions and not always.

Comment: Not my solution, but this post (https://blog.texei.com/get-live-notifications-when-the-record-youre-viewing-gets-modified-58c71cfddc0b) has a way to have a lightning component hook into the Change Data Capture API, and then you can fire a `toast` based on the result from that API call

Comment: One way is to override the layout with custom record forms and show the message using submit handler events

Answer (score 2):

Short of writing code, you can't implement this right now. There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) you should go vote on.

Comment: this idea is 12 years old :(

Comment: @sfdcfox yes.. the idea seems to be pretty old.. Looking for a workaround to handle this scenario..